# UINavigationController popViewControllerAnimated issue

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem, popviewcontrolleranimated

I have `LoginViewControllerIphone` instance , where I push the instance of `TasksRootViewControllerIphone`

then in `TasksRootViewControllerIphone` (10 seconds after appearing) I call  `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

And receive an error:

```
[NSRecursiveLock isSystemItem]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3ba360
```

I tried to print navigation controller stack:

```
po [self.navigationController viewControllers]
$2 = 0x003445f0 <__NSArrayI 0x3445f0>(
<LoginViewControllerIphone: 0x3b73c0>,
<TasksRootViewControllerIphone: 0x3af290>
)
```

So it has proper view controllers. Any ideas how can it happen?

**update:**

pushing code:

```
           self.tasksRootViewControllerIphone = [[TasksRootViewControllerIphone alloc] initWithNibName:@"TasksRootViewControllerIphone" bundle:nil];
            self.tasksRootViewControllerIphone.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            [self.loginViewControllerIphone.navigationController pushViewController:self.tasksRootViewControllerIphone animated:YES];
```

in TasksRootViewControllerIphone.m I have:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(popCurrentViewControllerAnimated) withObject:self afterDelay:10];
}

- (void)popCurrentViewControllerAnimated
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: check https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSRecursiveLock_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I can't find the solution there

Comment: can you post some code of pushing view controller my friend??

Comment: post your TasksRootViewControllerIphone excutable methods while launching, Mostly this is happening in your ViewDidLoad method.

Comment: I updated with pushing code and view did load code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the point.

The problem was because it's not arc project, and one of the UIBarButtonItems was released one time more.

Strange, but it caused the problem with popViewController.

Answer (score 1):

Update your viewDidload Method as

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(popCurrentViewControllerAnimated) withObject:nil afterDelay:10];
}
```

hopefully it solve your problem.

As the method `popCurrentViewControllerAnimated` not take any argument. so `withObject` should be `nil`. not `self`.

Comment: what is new ? check question proper

Comment: @kirti As in question in viewDidLoad Method {[self performSelector:@selector(popCurrentViewControllerAnimated) withObject:self afterDelay:10];} which is wrong.

Comment: it's now wrong, because I have a separate method popCurrentViewControllerAnimated, and I use @selector(popCurrentViewControllerAnimated)